# How remap "go back" Chrome (ALT+arrow left) to ALT+H like Vim?

Tags: google-chrome, vim, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events, xfce

Setup: Debian/GNU Xubuntu, Google Chrome latest version (auto update).

Hi folks,

I browse a lot, and I use some adjusted scripts to work only with my keyboard without use of mouse. I configured everything in the way that I have only use the home row (asdf...)  to navigate and work everything from my home row. Works like a charm.

But there is still one thing. When you browse around, and you would like to go back to previous page, you can just press Backspace in Windows environment. In Linux, you need to press ALT+arrow left.

I often go back to previous page. So I must move my hands to the arrow keys. I would like to remap this in Google Chrome. In the way that when I press ALT+H (like Vim), I could go back to previous page.

Any ideas how manage this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [shortcut manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortcut-manager/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf) extension allows you to customise keyboard shortcuts.  You can easily remap alt-h to back and and alt-l to forward with this extension (and a bunch of other actions too).